# Camera records upside down sometimes

Tags: android, camera, orientation, landscape, mediarecorder

When i am in landscape, if it's at 0degrees, it captures a good video, but if i turn the phone over 180 degrees, it will record upside down, how can i change this?
When i start recording i do this code:

```
myMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mySurfaceHolder.getSurface());

        if (rotationInDegreeValue == 90) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "set orientation hint : " + 0);
            myMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);
        } else if (rotationInDegreeValue == 270) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "set orientation hint : " + 180);// 180
            myMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(180);
        }

        myMediaRecorder.prepare();
        myMediaRecorder.start();
```

Then, i have an orientation listener:

```
orientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(getActivity(), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            LogService.log(TAG, "onOrientationChanged");

            if ((myCamera == null)) {
                return;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "orientation changed : " + orientation);
            if (((orientation < 45) || (orientation > 315) || ((orientation < 225) && (orientation > 135))) && !isRecording) {
                if (!isAlertShown && !isUserListDisplayed) {
                    // AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    // alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Orientation").setMessage("Return to landscape").setCancelable(false);
                    // orientationAlert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    // orientationAlert.show();
                    isAlertShown = true;
                }

            } else {
                if (isAlertShown) {
                    // orientationAlert.hide();
                    // orientationAlert.dismiss();
                    isAlertShown = false;
                }
            }
            rotateCamera();
        }
    };
```

This is the RotateCamera Function:

```
private void rotateCamera() {

    LogService.log(TAG, "rotateCamera()");

    int cameraId = CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

    if (isUsingBackCam) {
        cameraId = CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    }
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo myCameraInfo = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, myCameraInfo);
    Display display;
    display = getActivity().getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    int rotation = display.getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        degrees = 0;
        rotationInDegreeValue = 0;
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = size.x;

        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        degrees = 90;
        rotationInDegreeValue = 90;
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = size.y;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        degrees = 180;
        rotationInDegreeValue = 180;
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        rotationInDegreeValue = 270;
        degrees = 270;
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = size.y;
        break;
    }
    int result;
    if (myCameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (myCameraInfo.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
        result = ((myCameraInfo.orientation - degrees) + 360) % 360;
    }
    if (!isRecording) {
        try {
            myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogService.err(TAG, e.getMessage(), e, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

What do i have to do, to stop the camera from recording upside down, when i turn the phone 180 degrees. I tried to comment out the orientation listener, but still no luck.
Also, i do not know if it is important of not, but this happens in a fragment. The Activity of the fragment, does not have onconfigurationchanged set.

Comment: As the code is know, if the phone is turned 180 degrees, when i start recording, the video, is normal, while i record, and if i turn to phone to normal (0 degrees), it still is normal. The problem is that if i want to watch the video, the recorded video start by being upside down (instead of normal), and only turns normal, when i turn the phone to 0 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setOrientationHint function worked, but i had to append more videos, and when this was happening, the composition matrix of the videos was getting lost.
I have changed in the manifest, from SensorLandscape to Landscape, and this is how i solved this issue.